# Adding data from Soring boot app to Mondo DB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm building my first Spring app and for now, I want to save recipe object in my Mongo database.
I'm using .jsp file for the "frontend" part.

My problem is that the object is saved in the database but with null values.

What do I miss here?

AppController:

```
package era;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private RecipeRepo repo;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addRecipe")
    public String addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        System.out.println(recipe.getName());
        repo.save(recipe);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

home.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3 align="center">Recipe App</h3> <br><be>

<form action="addRecipe">
    ID: <input type="text" name="uid"/> <br><be>
    User Name: <input type="text" name="userName"/> <br><be>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>     
</body> 
</html>
```

RecipeRepository:

```
package era;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
public interface RecipeRepo extends MongoRepository<Recipe, Integer>{
}
```

Recipe:

```
package era;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection  = "recipe")
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    private int uid;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {   return uid; }
    public void setId(int uid) {   this.uid = uid; }
    public String getName() {   return name; }
    public void setName(String name) {   this.name = name;}
}
```

After entering id and username, this is the line printed in the console:

```
2020-05-20 17:48:33.057  INFO 4916 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:36}] to localhost:27017
```

Comment: What do you see in console?

Comment: 2020-05-20 17:48:33.057  INFO 4916 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:36}] to localhost:27017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am seeing is you haven't binded the jsp form to the pojo.

Be sure to use name in jsp form to match the pojo attributes and use value to capture the data.

You can try something like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3 align="center">Recipe App</h3> <br><be>

<form action="addRecipe">
    ID: <input type="text" name="uid" value="${recipe.uid}"/> <br><be>
    User Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="${recipe.name}"/> <br><be>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>     
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It's work! Thank you very much. In case of an array that I want to save using checkbox, do I need to write the value field at the same way?   value = "${recipe.ingridient}"?

Comment: Yes, you are right, you need to use the el expression to capture the data, also use dedicated mapping like ```@GetMapping```,```@PostMapping``` based on your requirement then using ```@RequestMapping``` on a controller. You can find numerous examples on web regarding this. Happy Coding!!